# Embed html button in GTK3 app?

Tags: python, html, gtk, embed

I'd like to embed a Yandex.Money "Donate" html button into my GTK3 (Python) app. Is it possible somehow?

This is the code of the button:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" src="https://money.yandex.ru/embed/small.xml?uid=41001442490707&amp;button-text=04&amp;button-size=l&amp;button-color=orange&amp;targets=Some+text!&amp;default-sum=50" frameborder="0" height="54" scrolling="no" width="auto"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; you'll have to use a `WebKit.WebView` widget and load the button's HTML code inside it.

Since the above solution is a bit overkill for just one button, perhaps it would be better to create the button yourself as a `Gtk.Button`, and access Yandex.Money's API (if they have one) in its `clicked` signal handler.

**Additional info**:

Here is an example of listening to the new window and navigation signals:

```
webview.connect('navigation-policy-decision-requested', _on_navigation)
webview.connect('new-window-policy-decision-requested', _on_navigation)

def _on_navigation(webview, frame, request, action, decision):
    print 'Tried to navigate to {}'.format(request.props.uri)
    return False  # not handled, proceed with default action
```

Comment: Thank you! I have also already thought about webkit, but haven't yet tried it.

I am not sure, I think, they have an API for that... I'll look into it!

Comment: For now I have been able to use WebKit.WebView to load the html code, after I press the button there nothing happens - the link neither opens in the main browser, nor in the WebView - what is wrong?

Comment: Probably it is trying to open a new window or tab. You could read the `new-window-policy-decision-requested` signal to see if this is the case. Alternatively, you could read the `navigation-policy-decision-requested` signal to find out what URI is being read and so gain a clue into why it is not doing anything.

Comment: Could you please show an example of that? I am sorry, my internet connection is very bad for a few days...

Comment: Clicking on such button in Firefox causes it to open the link in a new tab - does it mean, that this is the case with the WebView? If yes, how do I make the link open in the system's default browser?